# Array Display Order

Tags: arrays, arraylist, nsmutablearray

```
a=Array.new 
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
puts a
```

then output will be `1,2,3,4,5`, but I want to display `a[1]` to `a[0]`
(`2,3,4,5,1`).

Are there any built-in methods for display in the above order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no built in method to display it in the order you want - you would have to customize/implement your own toString (or similar) method/utility to achieve an arbitrary display of array elements

Comment: sorry array need to be display 2,3,4,5,1 and 3,4,5,1,2